# How do I draw a bubbled in semicircle in ObjectiveC and Cocoa for macOS?

Tags: objective-c, macos, user-interface, cocoa

How do I draw a bubbled in semicircle in ObjectiveC and Cocoa (on macOS, not iOS)? Currently, I am able to make a very simple circle that fits my needs like this:

```
NSRect rect = CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, 2*radius, 2*radius)
rect.cornerRadius = radius
```

This makes a full circle, but how do I make a semicircle, fully shaded in? The reason I am using this particular method of drawing a circle is because it is easy for me to add "rect" to the frame of a CAShapeLayer, which is the argument that

```
[[self layer] addSublayer:rect];
```

takes, where self refers to the current CocoaView.

Example:

[image: semicircle]

Lastly, this needs to be done in Core Animation, not with the iOS framework (as the tags imply).

Comment: What do you mean by "draw a bubbled in semicircle"? Do you want to draw a portion of a circle (an arc), but not full circle? Or something more oval shaped? Bottom line, perhaps you can edit your question, sharing a picture or what you mean. In answer to your question, you could create a `NSBezierPath` and `stroke` it (e.g., in the `drawRect` of custom `NSView` subclass). Or you can create `CGPathRef` and set it to be the path for a `CAShapeLayer`. But the specifics of the path depend entirely upon what this "bubbled" looks like.

Comment: @Rob--I've added a better explanation with picture of "bubbled in".

Answer (score 1):

This is the code for drawing the arc using UIBezierPath. 
It's not exactly what you want, but you can change the radius

```
     - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
        UIBezierPath *blueHalf = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [blueHalf addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(100, 100) radius:90.0 startAngle:-M_PI_2 endAngle:M_PI_2 clockwise:YES];
        [blueHalf setLineWidth:4.0];
        [[UIColor blueColor] setStroke];
        [blueHalf stroke];
   }
```

if you want to do this in Core Graphics:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextAddArc(context, 100, 100, 90, -M_PI_2, M_PI_2, FALSE);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answers! I am still new to Cocoa, so in my file containing drawRect, what import or include statement should I add (for either answer)? Also, your image shows a semicircle that is not filled in (like the semicircle depicted in the answer). How might I fill it in?

Comment: You will need to @import UIKit  in order to use UIBezierPath here's the link  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIBezierPath

Comment: Additionally, the image you have showed is a semicircle that is definitely not filled in, like the semicircle in my answer. Please make sure that your answer reflects my image in this way.